# Semi transparent dynamic mask on over dynamic UIView

Tags: ios, transparency, calayer, mask

Not sure where to look for this but I want to create a semi transparent mask of a view or layer that can move, change opacity and have multiple on screen at once that overlap.

Something to this effect:

[image]

Where the two small boxes can move around and change the opacity of the colour.

I have tried with `CALayer` mask but that is just punch through so I added a `CAShapeLayer` in the hole but you can see the edges. I tried using `allowsEdgeAntialiasing` on the `CAShapeLayer` but that didn't seem to work.

Other examples I've seen only work with UIImageViews because they use two UIImageViews on top of each other to get the effect. Unfortunately I need this to work over any kind of UIView.

I also tried using `CGBlendMode.SourceOut` which works well except the overlapping areas are lighter, which makes total sense but not what I'm after.

```
let blendMode = CGBlendMode.SourceOut

CGContextSaveGState(context)

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.75).CGColor)
CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

CGContextSetBlendMode(context, blendMode)

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.25).CGColor)
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 500, 60, 50))

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 1).CGColor)
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 550, 60, 50))
```

The last two fill rects overlap and the first is to set the entire view to have a semi transparent overlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can use the blend modes:

- Normal for the background
- Clear for holes for the squares
- Normal again for the squares to give the overlapping look

[image]

This doesn't appear to show edges around the squares when the second box is set to the same alpha as the background

[image]

This code generates the top image (called in drawRect):

```
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.Normal)
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.75).CGColor)
CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.Clear)
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 1).CGColor)
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(20, 150, 100, 100))
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 1).CGColor)
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(50, 200, 100, 100))

CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.Normal)
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.25).CGColor)
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(20, 150, 100, 100))
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.15).CGColor)
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(50, 200, 100, 100))
```